# Are there any actively maintained tools that can transform C++ code to xml?

Tags: c++, xml, abstract-syntax-tree

Are there any tools that can transform C++ code to xml, or some other format that would be easier to parse?
It would be great if it would also have the option of turning xml back to C++ . I already know of doxygen's xml format ... maybe it's just me, but I don't find it particularly helpful.

Comment: Since there's no clear correspondence between C++ and XML, what do you want to do with the XML?  Apparently you want the entire program in XML, and presumably not just as one big entry between `<program>` and `</program>`.

Comment: Given that C++ is an imperative programming language, and XML is a data description language, why exactly would you want to do this? (Not picking, just curious)

Comment: @David Thornley & @BillyONeal , I'd like to extract all the fields & methods defined in a class. Parsing xml seems easier than parsing C++.

Comment: You don't want to build an C++ parser.  That takes years.

Comment: @... this question gets repeatedly asked about C++.  People rightfully don't want to build a C++ parser, and hope they can get a predigested form of C++ which has arguably already been parsed, a la GCCXML suggested in answers below.  What they really want is *fully* predigested C++, which for me means a full, disambiguated parse tree retaining comments and augmented with symbol table data, which in fact is harder to get than just a parse tree.  GCCXML goes halfway to providing parsed declarations and symbol table data related to that, but doesn't provide details of function bodies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like [gcc xml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html)?

Comment: No, it only gives you XML output. Also note that gcc-xml doesn't give you access to function bodies - if you need access to them its the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2):

As i recently learned, [clangs C++ support](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) is nearing completion and its [API](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classes.html) (the classes prefixed with `CXX`) looks quite good.
Maybe its current support is sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has a [full C++ parser with symbol table](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html), and can directly produce XML for the parse tree.   DMS is designed to be customized; it would be close to trivial to get it to dump the symbol table as XML.  It provides full access to declarations *and* function body information.  Note that the XML can be pretty large for a 1000 line C++ program.

However, once you have the XML, you aren't going to be able to regenerate C++ source code from it.

DMS is designed to support custom analysis and code generation tasks.  If you stay "inside" DMS you can generate C++ ASTs and symbol table data to your heart's content, analyze the code for issues, and/or transform the C+ ASTs and when done, prettyprint the ASTs back to legal, compilable C++ code.

Yes, its actively maintained.